# Scripting error unexpected token

Tags: shell

i'm new here, and i wanted to understand why my programm doesn't work.
Can you help me ? 
thank you

Error

```
./mytry.sh: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./mytry.sh: line 28: `fi'
```

```
!/bin/sh

echo "find?"
read find 

if [ -z find ];
then 
echo "Ok"
fi

if [ ! -z $find ];
then
echo " You are in $(pwd)"
echo " I'm searching "

for element in $(ls)
do
echo $element

if [ -d $ element ];
then 
echo $element "exist and is not empty"
fi 
fi
done
```

Comment: `if [ -d $ element ];` => `if [ -d $element ];` use www.shellcheck.net to validate it

Comment: close the for loop before if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two syntax based mistakes. The shebang was written wrongly and the `fi` in the last line should come after `done`.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "find?"
read find 

if [ -z find ];
then 
echo "Ok"
fi

if [ ! -z $find ];
then
echo " You are in $(pwd)"
echo " I'm searching "

for element in $(ls)
do
echo $element

if [ -d $ element ];
then 
echo $element "exist and is not empty"
fi 
done 
fi
```

Above is the corrected script.

Answer (score 0):

!/bin/sh

echo "find?"
  read find

```
if [ -z find ];
then 
 echo "Ok"
```

fi

if [ ! -z $find ];
   then
    echo " You are in $(pwd)"
    echo " I'm searching "

```
for element in $(ls)
do
  echo $element

  if [ -d $ element ];
  then 
     echo $element "exist and is not empty"
  fi 
done
```

fi #should close after for loop